# Why during a matrix multiplication operation does a variable for storing the accumulating sum is faster then directly accessing the resulting cell?

Tags: c, memory, matrix-multiplication

I'm very new to algorithms and memory optimizations and trying to improve my general understanding of it.
I'm sure this is a very basic question, however I didn't manage to find an answer on my own and was hoping someone can help me shed some light on this.

When implementing matrix multiplication in C, assuming the matrices are stored as 2D NxN arrays, the naive and most basic approach for this task can be written as:

```
for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    for (j=0; j<N; j++)
        for (k=0; k<N; k++)
            c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][i];
```

However, another simple approach introduces a variable for storing the accumulating sum for each cycle of the third loop, i.e the sum of products of the elements in i_th row with the elements in the j_th column (term-by-term) and then assigning it to the product matrix.
As written in the following code:

```
for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<N; j++) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (k=0; k<N; k++) {
            sum += a[i][k]*b[k][j];
        }
        c[i][j] = sum;
    }
}
```

I can't understand why the second code is considered to run a little bit faster then the first basic code ?

Thank you in advance for you help

Comment: Not sure it's relevant (need to examine assembly), but `c[i][j]` involves a bunch of multiplications and additions (`c[i][j]` ==> **kinda, approximately** ==> `*(c + i*sizeof c[i] + j*sizeof c[i][j])`)

Comment: The second version does fewer memory writes.  In the first version, every element of `c` is written to `N+1` times (the `+1` is due to having to zero it in advance, which you didn't show).  The second version writes each element of `c` once, with no need to zero it in advance.  That's the difference.  When optimized, `sum` will be kept in a register.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help. Isn't the second approach also writes the same number of times (N+1) to the variable sum like the first one does to c ? Or is this avoided when sum is kept in a register ? @TomKarzes

Comment: @nirt If it's in a register, then no memory access is required to write to it.

Comment: @TomKarzes And if we consider that sum isn't in the register, is this still hold true ? Does we still do less memory writing operations in comparison to the first version as well ?

Comment: @nirt If you don't optimize, you'll be running a lot slower regardless, but even if `sum` is in memory, writing to it is still probably cheaper than doing a doubly-indexed write to `c`, since there is come cost associated with the index calculation.

Comment: Thank you both for the replies I think I understand it better now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a subroutine is passed pointers `a`, `b`, and `c`, the compiler generally does not know where they point. Therefore, in `c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][i]`, the compiler must allow for the possibility that updates to `c[i][j]` may change elements of `a` and `b` that will be used in future iterations of the loops. The way it commonly does this is to write each update to the memory of `c[i][j]`.

With `sum += a[i][k] * b[k][i]`, the compiler knows that `sum` cannot overlap `a` or `b` because `sum` is locally created. Therefore it can optimize this code by keeping the sum in a register and only writing to memory once, when `c[i][j] = sum;` is executed.